# Robot-Framework SSH Library : Login without a password

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I am trying to use the Login keyword for a user without a password and it does not seem possible. After a bit of research I could not find an answer.

After

```
Open Connection | hostname
```

I tried

```
Login | ${user} | ${EMPTY}

Login | ${user}
```

`Login | ${user} | ${pass}` Where ${pass} was just declared in the variables table...

To no avail...

I also tried to include the username in the hostname with : user@hostname, but that did not work either.

I know this could be possible with the keyword 'Login With Public Key', however this is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Is there a workaround, or a simple solution that I'm missing ?

Thank you

Comment: SSH library uses paramiko as backend, and paramiko does not support it out of the box (https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/890). Some modification in paramiko is required:
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/compare/master...mzakharo:master
Possibly you could extend robotframework-sshlibrary adding some keyword to login without password.

Comment: Yes I tried to create my own keyword using paramiko only to realize that...

Comment: Why would someone use the Secure Shell Protocol to allow access to a user without authentication? The user may not have password but if using a certificate will allow them to login. Is this not a solution for you?